# how to use sed to substitute a string with another string starting with $?

Tags: linux, bash, regex, sed

I want to replace the content of a file

```
cat test.sh
attribute = "metaapp"
```

so I am trying to replace the `metaapp` with string `${meta.app}` with hep of sed using

```
 sed -i s/metaapp/${meta.app}/g test.sh
```

and getting bad substitution error . How to use sed here so the output will looks like this

```
attribute = "${meta.app}"
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not about `sed`, it's about the *shell*.

`${meta.app}` is almost like the syntax for the parameter substitution (other names: variable substitution, variable expansion): `${var}`. Variable names cannot contain dots. There is syntax like `${var-foo}` where `-` does not belong to the name either, there are more of them; but `${var.foo}` or `${meta.app}` is not defined.

That's why your shell complained about bad substitution. `sed` was not even started. Try `mumblemumble ${meta.app}` and the error will be the same. You won't see an error saying the `mumblemumble` command was not found; the shell won't get this far.

To fix, single-quote the entire sed expression:

```
sed -i 's/metaapp/${meta.app}/g' test.sh
```

Strings in single-quotes are not expanded by the shell. You can achieve the same result by escaping troublesome characters, while double-quoting or not quoting at all (`s/metaapp/\${meta.app}/g`). But you need to know *what* characters to escape in which case. With single-quotes you easily protect the entire string.

That's how you move the shell out of the way. It would not be so easy if you needed a literal `'` inside the string, or any kind of substitution from the shell. Fortunately you don't, so single-quoting is convenient and the right thing to do. Now you only need to care how `sed` interprets the string.